# Bender.js: "bender server run" command opens the bender.js config file in directory instead of starting bender.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, bender.js

I am new to bender.js and I am trying to run the example project at: 
https://github.com/benderjs/benderjs-example-project
After going through the installation steps,
I am unable to access bender.js server at:

```
http://localhost:1030
```

I have installed bender.js and all the dependencies stated in the example project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to executing the ".js" from the command prompt. As it turns out, Windows executes ".js" files with WSH or the default program(notepad in my case) associated with the file extension. 
Executing the same script from a PowerShell or Git Shell or any other UNIX based shells should solve the issue.