# Bender.js Error: 'module' is undefined

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, automated-tests, bender.js

I am trying to setup a test environment for ckeditor as described [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_tests).

After installing bender, when I run bender init, I am getting a JS error at line 129 of [bender.js](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/bender.js) saying 'module' is undefined.

Here's a screenshot of the error dialog -

[image]

I am not sure if this is due to any bug in [bender.js](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/bender.js)... I followed the previous steps and all succeeded.

Any direction on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're running the file with wrong interpreter. You're using [JScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript), which is a Microsoft language.

Bender is a JavaScript application and is designed to be ran by NodeJS interpreter.

Make sure that you have NodeJS installed as mentioned in Setting up Bender.js, then use command line to run Bender.

Comment: Actually - this question is a DUP of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787140/bender-js-bender-server-run-command-opens-the-bender-js-config-file-in-direct and you'll find the answer there.

Comment: Thanks! gonna trying it out